# Pandas Time Series - add a value to the first value in each year

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a `Pandas` time series with unevenly spaced dates/datapoints. I want to add 1 to the value of each data point that is the first value for each year.
The time series is very sparse and the data is sorted.

Is there a better way to do this then by looping through all data points and checking when the year changes?

**Example:**

```
dates = [datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 1), datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 2), datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0 ,0), datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime(2014, 1, 3, 1, 1)]

ts = Series(np.random.randn(len(dates)), dates)
```

Using the example above I want to add 1 to value on `2012-01-01 01:01:00`, `2013-01-02 00:00:00` and `2014-01-03 01:01:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can extract the year:

```
ts.index.year
```

Find where the adjacent difference is nonzero:

```
np.diff(ts.index.year) != 0
```

Remember that you also want to select the very first data point:

```
np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(ts.index.year) != 0))
```

And then modify those data points:

```
ts[np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(ts.index.year) != 0))] += 1
```